# How to Remove Homepage or Pages Paginated in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

**Example:**

```
domain.com/page/2/
domain.com/page/3/
etc.
```

**domain.com/page/1/** is good to redirect to homepage. But any number after **/page/** it not redirect or showing 404 error page

I have no pagination plugin or anything. All of the pages are just copies of my homepage.

I want it redirect to 404 page or back to homepage. Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on Settings->Reading->
Your homepage displays, if the homepage is set as a static frontpage or posts pages. If you don't want to have any pagination on the homepage, you have to make sure that **static page** is selected for the homepage.

[image]